# Raw pointer of std::shared_ptr returns base instead of derived

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

```
class Base
{
  bool a;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  bool b;
};

void main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<Base> base(new Derived());
}
```

So in this example the raw pointer of shared_ptr will point to an instance of Base, NOT Derived. Which I do not understand.

```
class Base
{
  virtual void foo() {}
  bool a;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  virtual void foo() {}
  bool b;
};

void main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<Base> base(new Derived());
}
```

But in this case the raw pointer of shared_ptr does point to Derived? I'm sure I'm missing something. can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: The pointers point to `Derived` instances in both cases. Shared pointers aren't different from raw pointers in this regard.

Comment: How are you determining what it points to, the debugger? If the base class doesn't have at least one virtual function, certain information is not embedded in the class to determine its type, and the debugger may not be able to deduce its derived type.

Comment: @NeilKirk The debugger I use often can't deduce the type even if the class is polymorphic.  (But of course, if `Base` isn't polymorphic, the debugger has no chance of knowing that it is in fact a `Derived`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze VS debugger can usually tell from polymorphic base.

Comment: @NeilKirk That's not been my experience.  It only displays the base class data (which is usually empty, because the base class is an interface).  I can get the _name_ of the most derived class, because it's mangled into the name of the vtable, but that's about it.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I just tried in VS2013, it works.

Comment: @NeilKirk I'm using VS2013, and all I get, in general, is the base class.  Most of the time, the derived class and the base class are both in different projects than where I've stopped; and the derived class is in an unnamed namespace.  Maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: @JamesKanze This is my testcase http://pastebin.com/2H4hpkdx

Comment: @NeilKirk All in the same source file.  Not very realistic; in our application, it is extremely rare for the derived class to even be in the same project as the base, much less in the same source file.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, the classes do not have a virtual table, since there are no virtual functions.
This means, that since the shared_ptr expects a static type of Base, it will store a Base.
The second case also stores a Base, but the existence of a virtual table allows you to see that the dynamic type of the object is Derived.

Comment: The shared_ptr stores neither a base nor a derived. It stores pointers. Where (1) these pointers point and what (2) the pointers' type is and (3) which member functions are executed at run time are three distinct issues.

Comment: In both cases, the pointer stores a pointer to a `Base`, which is a sub-object of the `Derived`, which continues to exist.  The fact that `Base` is polymorphic in the second case makes it easier and more natural to access the `Derived`, but what is stored, and what it points to, are the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

First, the use of `std::shared_ptr` here is a red herring.  In
this case, both `std::shared_ptr` and a raw pointer behave
exactly the same.  In both cases, the expression `new Derived()`
returns a `Derived*` which points to the entire object.  And in
both cases, using it to initialize a pointer to `Base`, be it
a raw pointer or any reasonably designed smart pointer will
cause the `Derived*` to be converted to a `Base*`, which points
to the `Base` sub-object in the `Derived`.  The `Derived` object
still exists, however, and can be accessed in several different
ways: via virtual functions, by using `std::dynamic_cast` *if* 
`Base` is polymorphic (has at least one virtual function), by
using `std::static_cast` if you're 100% sure that the pointed to
object actually is a `Derived`, and probably some others I've
not thought of.  In your first case, only the last is possible,
since in the first, `Base` is not polymorphic.  In both of your
examples, however, the pointer points to a `Base`, which is
a subobject of a larger `Derived`.

There are some differences between `std::shared_ptr` and a raw
pointer.  For example, in your first example, replacing
`std::shared_ptr<Base>` with `Base*` and manually deleting
through the pointer will result in undefined behavior;
`std::shared_ptr` has extra complications to avoid this.  (But
the complications aren't without their drawbacks.  Give `Base`
a virtual destructor, as it should have, and then make the
destructor of `Derived` private, for whatever strange reason,
and your first example won't compile.)